# Why does pandas grouping-aggregation discard categoricals column?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, categories, pandas-groupby

### Situation

Consider the following two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd  # version 0.23.4

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'B': [100, 100, 200, 100, 100],
    'C': ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'mango', 'orange'],
    'D': ['jupiter', 'mercury', 'mars', 'venus', 'venus'],
})

df2 = df1.astype({'D': 'category'})
```

As you can see in dataframe `df2` the column  `D` is of [categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) data type, but otherwise `df2` is identical to `df1`.

Now consider the following groupby-aggregation operations:

```
result_x_df1 = df1.groupby(by='A').first()
result_x_df2 = df2.groupby(by='A').first()
result_y_df1 = df1.groupby(by=['A', 'B']).first()
result_y_df2 = df2.groupby(by=['A', 'B']).first()
```

with results looking as follows:

```
In [1]: result_x_df1
Out[1]:
     B      C        D
A
1  100  apple  jupiter
2  100  mango    venus

In [2]: result_x_df2
Out[2]:
     B      C        D
A
1  100  apple  jupiter
2  100  mango    venus

In [3]: result_y_df1
Out[3]:
           C        D
A B
1 100  apple  jupiter
  200  mango     mars
2 100  mango    venus

In [4]: result_y_df2
Out[4]:
           C
A B
1 100  apple
  200  mango
2 100  mango
```

### Question

`result_x_df1`, `result_x_df2` and `result_y_df1` look exactly as I would have expected. What really puzzles me however is that in `result_y_df2` the **categoricals column `D` has been completely discarded**. This raises the questions:

- Why is categoricals column `D` discarded in `result_y_df2`?
- How can I prevent categoricals column `D` from being discarded, i.e. how I can obtain a grouping-aggregation result from `df2` that looks similar to `result_y_df1`?

Comment: `.head(1)` might help, still curious why `first` discards categorical column

Comment: @Dark Using `head(1)` instead of `first()` indeed seems to resolve the issue!

Comment: Pandas version 0.21.0 gave expected result. The updated version must have changed some thing.

Comment: @RaunaqJain Interesting. I wonder whether the change in behaviour compared to `pandas` 0.21.0 is a bug or a deliberate modification?

Comment: I would love to debug it. Sadly, I have no clue how to go about doing it. If someone can guide me through, I will be grateful. Nice opportunity to learn.

Comment: Pandas version 0.23 has the following lines added `if 'min_count' not in kwargs:
                    kwargs['min_count'] = min_count` which is not in v0.21

Comment: The issue has now been reported to the pandas devs: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22512

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the cause of the issue is a regression bug in pandas (occurring from version `0.23.0` onwards). A work-around is to use `head(1)` instead of `first()` (as suggested by Dark).

See [this pandas github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22512) for new developments.